# Plotting two variables as lines using R on the same graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, line

l have a file having two fields. l want to plot a line plot where x-axis will be days and y-axis will be the frequency of AA and BB. and lines will be AA and BB. I tried some R packages but could not get it. Any lead would be appreciated.

```
Disease days
AA  7
AA  5
AA  5
AA  15
AA  4
AA  15
AA  5
AA  7
BB  4
BB  3
BB  11
BB  6
BB  12
BB  6
BB  9
BB  20
BB  4
BB  2
```

Comment: Why did you remove your sample data? A screenshot is *always* a bad idea, as we can't copy and paste data.

Comment: Disease days
AA 7
AA 5
AA 5
AA 15
AA 4
AA 15
AA 5
AA 7
BB 4
BB 3
BB 11
BB 6
BB 12
BB 6
BB 9
BB 20
BB 4
BB 2

Comment: I had no option to add datafile so added an image.

Comment: @Gab Don't add data/code in comments. I've reversed your edit to include the original data as text (which is one of the preferred ways of sharing data around here). For future posts, please review how to provide a [minimal & reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MauritsEvers, thanks for your suggestions. I will not add data in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    group_by(Disease, days) %>%
    summarise(Freq = n()) %>%
    ggplot(aes(days, Freq, colour = Disease)) +
    geom_line()
```

[image]

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Disease days
AA  7
AA  5
AA  5
AA  15
AA  4
AA  15
AA  5
AA  7
BB  4
BB  3
BB  11
BB  6
BB  12
BB  6
BB  9
BB  20
BB  4
BB  2", header = T)
```